# Having an issue with iPad display

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive

I am having a problem with our site not displaying the CSS while on iPads.

Here is what I have done so far:

Works fine on mobile. In addition when I use browser console to view as iPad it works fine and when I use a site to view the page as an ipad it also works fine

However on a physical iPad none of the styling kicks in and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be very much appreciated.

We are using a html include for the CSS scripts - could this be an issue?

The site is:

www.roburir.com/index.html (we are working on getting rid of the index.html displaying).

Answer (score 1):

You are using HTML imports to load content including header content, which has [very little browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports). Just use a PHP include to import stuff, or normal CSS links that have worked fine for decades. :)

Comment: The site is hosted through Azure (.asp net), which doesn't accept php. Is this the issue? If so may have to add all the css by hand which is a bit of a pain

Comment: Each language has its own means of including files—Asp included: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524876(v=vs.90).aspx